# Notifications between buyer and seller

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, session, ado

I have two different tables and web-forms like seller and buyer I am trying to send a notification from particular buyer to particular seller.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to help you, but your question is a little unclear, and quite broad. Are those database tables, or tables in a web forms GUI? Are the buyers and sellers clients that log on to your server, or are they local instances of some sort? What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck? (Please provide some code to help clarify your problem if possible).

Comment: The sql tag is not well placed, you probably wouldn't use the database to do your notifications.  Welcome to SO btw

Answer (score 0):

Your Q is not clear. But it I am correct Your problem is If something changes in one table you want to notify the other also.

You can do this using code by [Observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

You want a direct notification in database then you can use triggers. I personally prefer Using code.

Comment: Thank you for you are help, i will do that using code only

Comment: After yuu get to the correct solution please write here or mark this as answers if this gets you on correct path.